# Unity doesn't run any project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have Mac Intel, MacOs Big Sur, Unity Hub and Unity 2021.2.14f1
In one day I opened the Unity hub and ran one of the projects but Unity was failed and exited without no explanation. Next time I tried to open in safe mode and got next error message in the console:

```
    Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code 134.
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> Bee.Stevedore.Program.HumaneException: 'cache-folder' could not be inferred from environment, nor was it configured in Stevedore.conf
   at Bee.Stevedore.Program.StevedoreConfig.GlobalConfig.get_CacheFolder()
   at Bee.Stevedore.Program.DownloadCache..ctor(StevedoreConfig config, Action`1 emitWarning)
   at Bee.Core.Stevedore.StevedoreUnpacker..ctor(Backend backend)
   at Bee.Core.RequirementsForRunningBuildCode..ctor(Backend backend)
   at Bee.Core.BuildProgramContext..ctor(String[] args, String buildTitle)
   at ScriptCompilationBuildProgram.ScriptCompilationBuildProgram.Main(String[] args) in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/IncrementalBuildPipeline/ScriptCompilationBuildProgram/ScriptCompilationBuildProgram.cs:line 19
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/netcorerun/netcorerun/Program.cs:line 47
```

The same issue appeared for rest projects and for new ones.
I started long googling of this problem. I tried to uninstall all Unity apps and cleaned all caches. Still have an error.
Also I found [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/bee-stevedore-program-humaneexception-cache-folder-could-not-be-inferred-from-environment.1315161/) with the same problem and followed instructions.
So I created a launcher file with next content:

```
#!/bin/bash
export HOME=/Users/sk # my users folder
nohup "/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity Hub" &>/dev/null &
```

And I lunched this file but still got the same error. Cannot still find no solution. Please help.

Comment: So. You’re building for windows?

Comment: No, for MacOs Big Sur

Comment: A) not male B) all the unity stuff says it gets that error because you targeted windows

Comment: @BugFinder Please clarify what do you mean?

Comment: How can I clarify more. The posts YOU provided say it produces that error because the target is windows

Comment: What means the target is Windows? Target of what? The only link I posted is a post with the issue on MacOs. Sorry for my missunderstanding
Also what means: not male?

Comment: The build target. All posts point to it saying windows.

Comment: Can you please give me a link to any post that expains this? How to change this build target? I'm new in Unity, sorry.

Comment: Sorry but we are not here to google stuff for you

Comment: So please just put the text here what exactly I have to google? Becase you know, I spent days for trying different google phrases.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as this and my fix was to repair my dll files, which I was doing for an unrelated thing and then Unity suddenly started working again

Comment: Dll is not compatible with mac. Maybe there could be something similar? Actually I've already minor uodated the MacOs to avoid any System bug.